# Solr prefix search with Roman numbers - Over Recall issue

Tags: indexing, solr, solr4, synonym, roman-numerals

**Solr Version** used : 4.10.*

**Problem Statement:** 

We have a unique problem where "6" is recalling "Vice" etc. strings i.e strings matching "vi*". We store all the prefixes of the titles in below manner

input : **vice** 
v 
**vi (this gets matched with synonym シックス,6,six,vi,ⅵ,六)** 
vic 
vice

**Analyzer Chain:**

```
<fieldType name="some_name" class="solr.TextField">
      <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.DelimitedPayloadTokenFilterFactory" delimiter="$" encoder="float"/>
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.DelimitedPayloadTokenFilterFactory" delimiter="$" encoder="float"/>
      </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

How do I get around the fact that "6" should not recall anything that matches "vi*" in the field? Similarly "5" is recalling everything that starts with "v*".

I can handle the tokenization out of the analyzer chain by having a synonyms in a map and only calling synonyms replacement when the roman numerical appear as space separated token but wanted to see if this can be done by the chain without any server side code.